# AjaxControlToolkit PopupExtender in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are in the process of migrating our ASP.NET application to use Jquery instead of AjaxControlToolkit. We use the popup extender quite extensively in our application. I was wondering if there exists a plugin in Jquery that does what the AjaxControlToolKits's PopupControl does. (It opens a popup window to the Center, Left, Right, Top,  or Bottom of the control that is specified). More information on PopupControl is available at  http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx .

Any help in directing me to find the right plugin will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqModal is a plugin for jQuery to help you display notices, dialogs, and modal windows in a web browser. It is flexible and tiny, akin to a "Swiss Army Knife", and makes a great base as a general purpose windowing framework.

A placeholder can be  added to your page to tell the modal dialog the precise location in which to open (i.e. under or around an existing control).

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/